# Why am I getting a 3px right margin?

Tags: html, css

I am getting a 3px margin-right on each image in the 4th table.

I think it is the reason I am getting problems with my html email. But I can't seem to figure out why this is happening!

Here is my html:

```
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  style="border-collapse: collapse; margin:0px; padding:0px;" width="600">
        <tr>
            <td style="border-collapse: collapse;" width="600" height="179">
            <div style="width:600px; height:179px; overflow:hidden;">
                <a href="http://www.anzie.com/"><img align="left" alt="Gold Rush" height="179" src="https://d2q0qd5iz04n9u.cloudfront.net/_ssl/proxy.php/http/gallery.mailchimp.com/5513172da1aa95c4b84fdedba/images/ESSETIAL6_FALL_01.jpg" style="height: 179px;  width: 600px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;  display:block; vertical-align: bottom; float: left; " width="600" /></a>
            </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  style="border-collapse: collapse; margin:0px; padding:0px;" width="600">
        <tr>
            <td style="border-collapse: collapse;" width="600" height="25">
                <div style="width:600px; height:25px; overflow:hidden;"><a href="http://www.anzie.com/viewall_gold.php"><img align="left" alt="Shop Gold" height="25" src="https://d2q0qd5iz04n9u.cloudfront.net/_ssl/proxy.php/http/gallery.mailchimp.com/5513172da1aa95c4b84fdedba/images/ESSETIAL6_FALL_02.1.jpg" style="height: 25px;  width: 600px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;  display:block; vertical-align: bottom; float: left; " width="600" /></a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  style="border-collapse: collapse; margin:0px; padding:0px;" width="600">
        <tr>
            <td style="border-collapse: collapse;" width="600" height="200">
                <div style="width:600px; height:200px; overflow:hidden;">
                <a href="http://www.anzie.com"><img align="left" alt="Gold Rush" height="200" src="https://d2q0qd5iz04n9u.cloudfront.net/_ssl/proxy.php/http/gallery.mailchimp.com/5513172da1aa95c4b84fdedba/images/ESSETIAL6_FALL_03.jpg" style="height: 200px;  width: 600px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;  display:block; vertical-align: bottom; float: left;" width="600" /></a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  style="border-collapse: collapse; margin:0px; padding:0px;" width="600">
        <tr>
            <td style="border-collapse: collapse;" width="226">
                <a href="http://www.anzie.com/dew-drop-collection-etoile-mini-ring-moonstone-p-2454.html"><img align="left" alt="Vintage Accent Ring" height="221" src="https://d2q0qd5iz04n9u.cloudfront.net/_ssl/proxy.php/http/gallery.mailchimp.com/5513172da1aa95c4b84fdedba/images/ESSETIAL6_FALL_04.jpg" style="width: 226px; height: 221px;  display:block; vertical-align: bottom; float: left;" width="226" /></a></td>
            <td style="border-collapse: collapse;" width="159">
                <a href="http://www.anzie.com/aztec-earrings-studs-mini-moonstone-clear-topaz-p-2508.html"><img align="left" alt="Minature Studs" height="221" src="https://d2q0qd5iz04n9u.cloudfront.net/_ssl/proxy.php/http/gallery.mailchimp.com/5513172da1aa95c4b84fdedba/images/ESSETIAL6_FALL_05.jpg" style="height: 221px;  width: 159px;  display:block; vertical-align: bottom; float: left;" width="159" /></a></td>
            <td style="border-collapse: collapse;" width="215">
                <a href="http://www.anzie.com/royale-ring-round-moonstone-p-1919.html"><img align="left" alt="Heirloom Ring" height="221" src="https://d2q0qd5iz04n9u.cloudfront.net/_ssl/proxy.php/http/gallery.mailchimp.com/5513172da1aa95c4b84fdedba/images/ESSETIAL6_FALL_06.jpg" style="height: 221px;  width: 215px;  display:block; vertical-align: bottom; float: left;" width="215" /></a></td>
        </tr>
</table>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  style="border-collapse: collapse; margin:0px; padding:0px;" width="600">
        <tr>
            <td style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                <a href="http://www.anzie.com/dew-drop-collection-etoile-earrings-moonstone-p-2498.html"><img align="left" alt="Evening Earrings" height="324" src="https://d2q0qd5iz04n9u.cloudfront.net/_ssl/proxy.php/http/gallery.mailchimp.com/5513172da1aa95c4b84fdedba/images/evening_earrrings.jpg" style="height: 324px;  width: 226px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;  display:block; vertical-align: bottom; float: left;" width="226" /></a></td>
            <td style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                <a href="http://www.anzie.com/aztec-necklace-sun-pendant-moonstone-diamonds-p-2509.html"><img align="left" alt="Statement Pendant" height="324" src="https://d2q0qd5iz04n9u.cloudfront.net/_ssl/proxy.php/http/gallery.mailchimp.com/5513172da1aa95c4b84fdedba/images/neckalce_center.jpg" style="height: 324px;  width: 159px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;  display:block; vertical-align: bottom; float: left;" width="159" /></a></td>
            <td style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                <a href="http://www.anzie.com/dew-drop-collection-bubble-stackable-bangle-gold-set-p-2510.html"><img align="left" alt="Versatile Bangles" height="324" src="https://d2q0qd5iz04n9u.cloudfront.net/_ssl/proxy.php/http/gallery.mailchimp.com/5513172da1aa95c4b84fdedba/images/ESSETIAL6_FALL_09.jpg" style="height: 324px;  width: 215px;  display:block; vertical-align: bottom; float: left;" width="215" /></a></td>
        </tr>
</table>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  style="border-collapse: collapse; margin:0px; padding:0px;" width="600">
        <tr>
            <td style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                <img align="left" height="74" src="https://d2q0qd5iz04n9u.cloudfront.net/_ssl/proxy.php/http/gallery.mailchimp.com/5513172da1aa95c4b84fdedba/images/border_bottom_left.jpg" style="width: 226px; height: 74px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;  display:block; vertical-align: bottom; float: left;" width="226" /></td>
            <td style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                <img align="left" height="74" src="https://d2q0qd5iz04n9u.cloudfront.net/_ssl/proxy.php/http/gallery.mailchimp.com/5513172da1aa95c4b84fdedba/images/bottom_center.jpg" style="width: 159px; height: 74px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;  display:block; vertical-align: bottom; float: left;" width="159" /></td>
            <td style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                <a href="http://www.anzie.com/locations.php"><img align="left" alt="Locate Store" height="74" src="https://d2q0qd5iz04n9u.cloudfront.net/_ssl/proxy.php/http/gallery.mailchimp.com/5513172da1aa95c4b84fdedba/images/ESSETIAL6_FALL_10.jpg" style="height: 74px;  width: 215px;  display:block; vertical-align: bottom; float: left;" width="215" /></a></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your HTML makes baby raptors cry. Please remove your presentational attributes (e.g. `border="0"` `cellpadding="0"`, etc), and don't use `<table>` for layout purposes.

Comment: This is for an HTML email so I'm pretty sure they are necessary unfortunately..

Comment: Stupid me I left out the margin:0 padding:0 for those three inline styles

Answer (score 1):

The tag `img` has a default `border-weight`. You must give it a bind.

`<img src="http://v.luq.cc/xxxxx.gif" border="0" />`

Like this.